# Update database in Gridview

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a gridview displaying some columns from database using `<asp:BoundField DataField="Leaves">`.

I also have an `ItemTemplate` with `textbox` that is supposed to add on the number of leaves the employee is taking. How do I update the value through the `textbox`?

Sorry for my bad English, it is not my first language. The idea behind this is:

1. Column `Leaves` records total number of leaves taken by the employee. E.g. Employee D already took 15 leaves this year.
2. Employee D takes another 3 days leaves, I type 3 in the `TextBox` and update then the total will become 18 days of leaves.
3. How do I do it in C#? How does my `TextBox ID="tb_leaves"` detect which row I am updating because every rows in the gridview has the same `TextBox`? By logic if I update using `tb_leaves` all the employees will be updated with the same number right?

Here is my coding:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvDL" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover grid" CellSpacing="0" rules="all" border="1" runat="server" Style="border-collapse: collapse;" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" PageSize="20" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDL_PageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="#" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Employee ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Full Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="toUpper" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="IC" HeaderText="IC Number" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Leaves" HeaderText="Leaves"/>

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Days Taken
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_leaves" Width="150" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:TemplateField>
         <HeaderTemplate>
             Update
         </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" onclick="Btn_Update_Click"/>
    </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="GridPager" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I wanted because when you update that way there's a risk of typing in wrong value, for example 18 days but typed 19 days of leave. That's why I used a textbox that should add number of days into the leaves column.

Comment: Well, you might need to adjust it to your needs.